# jQuery modify value on specific table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to programmatically modify a cell content.

this is how I am adding rows to my table:

```
addLine(id) {
  var newRow = $('<tr id=' + this.id + '>');
  var cols = "";

  cols += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
  cols += '<td id=s>test</td>';

  newRow.append(cols);
  $(".table").append(newRow);
  this.id++;
}
```

and this is how I tried to modify the cell on row `0` with id equl to `s`

```
//$(".table").find('tr#'+0).find('td:eq(1)').html("some other text");
```

This is not changin the content of the second `td` cell and I am not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working sample you just need to call `.find('#' + id)` to find the wanted row

```js
var id = 0;
var name = "abcdef";

function addLine() {
  var newRow = $('<tr id=' + id++ + '>');
  var cols = "";

  cols += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
  cols += '<td id=s>test</td>';

  newRow.append(cols);
  $(".table").append(newRow);
}

function changeValue() {
  $(".table").find('#' + 1).find('td:eq(1)').html("some other text");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addLine()">Add line </button>
<button onclick="changeValue()">Change Value </button>
<table class="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some stuff for you:

```
addLine(id){
  var newRow = "<tr id="+id+">";
  var cols = "";

  cols += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
  cols += '<td>test</td>'; // you are always setting the same id. just leave it blank

  newRow.append(cols);

  newRow = "</tr>"; // tr tag needs to be closed

  $(".table").append(newRow);
  id++;
}
```

And the query would be:

```
$('#'+searchId).children('td').eq(1).html("some other text"); //searchId = id of your row
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector for the 2nd td, you should do `td:nth-child(2)` to select the 2nd one.

Also, a quick note.  `<table>` automatically adds a `<tbody>` tag under it, so you should really do `$('.table tbody').append(newRow)`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all html ids and classes should not begin with numbers. Using jQuery you can do it without assigning ids to rows and columns.

Also note if your adding Ids make sure all ids are unique.

```js
var id = 1;

function addLine() {
  var name = "Row " + id + " column 1";
  var newRow = $('<tr>');
  var cols = "";

  cols += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
  cols += '<td>test</td>';

  newRow.append(cols);
  $(".table").append(newRow);
  id++;
}

function changeCell(row, col) {
  $(".table").find('tr').eq(--row).find('td').eq(--col).html("some other text");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addLine()">Add Line</button>
<!-- add two rows to change row 2 col 1 value -->
<button onclick="changeCell(2,1)">Change row 2 col 1</button>

<table class="table"></table>
```